# Payment gateway to transfer money like escrow

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, sdk, backend, payment-gateway

I want to implement payment flow with 2 types of users as explained below

1. Type1(Customer) user pays the amount to get the service.
2. This amount will go into merchant account.
3. Transfer this amount to Type2(Service provider) user from merchant account after Type2 user provides the service successfully.
4. If he/she fails to provide the service amount will be refunded back to Type1 user.

I have seen some payment gateways but mostly they don't support transfer of money from merchant account to the user, some payment gateways don't have mobile SDKs available, some don't support location.

Please help how can I implement this payment flow? or which payment gateway support this flow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use stripe manual payout for this.